# change profile picture laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I want each user to be able to change the image of their profile, I have tried several things but I can't get it to work and that the photo be uploaded and delete the previous one, someone can help me

```php
public function update(perfilrequest $request)
{
    $user = $request->user();

    $user->fill($request->validated());
    if($user->isDirty('email')){
        $user->email_verified_at= null;
        $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
    }

    $user->save();

    return redirect('/perfil')->withSuccess('DATOS GUARDADOS');
}

public function index()
{
    return view ('paginas.perfil');
}
```

My view

```html
<div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image">
```

I want to save it in this route: `storage/public/users`.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$user = $request->user();

$imageName = Carbon::now()->timestamp . '.' .$request->image->extension();
$user->profile_photo_path = $imageName;
$user->save();

$request->image->storeAs('users', $imageName);
```

In `config/filesystems.php` change storage root path:

```php
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('public'),
],
```

Comment: Class "App\Http\Controllers\Carbon" not found

Comment: import Carbon class ```use Carbon\Carbon;```

Comment: 'users' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/users'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/users',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],